# Read all values from xml tags with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xmlhttprequest

im currently working on reading a xml file, i have successfully read the xml file so far but the problem comes next, instead of reading the xml file tag one by one i want to read the tags that are inside the items tag and extract the value of each one

So far this is what i got

```js
var xmlDoc;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'prueba.xml');
xhr.send();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
 xmlDoc = xhr.responseXML;
 var items = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("items")[0];
 for(i=0;i<items.length;i++){
  item = items[i];
  $(item).each(function(i,val){
   console.log(val)
  })
 }
}
```

and here's the xml file

```html
<!DOCTYPE StreamControl>
<items>
 <timestamp>1510794812</timestamp>
 <nombre>ayy</nombre>
</items>
```

I think i'm close, any tips?

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear but one thing that stood out to me is that you have a variable `items` but assign it to a single item, then attempt to loop through that single item as if it was a set of items.

Comment: Make sure `xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200`, within `onreadystatechange`. I would also get into the habit of scoping off your `var`s with, at least, `var`, especially since your code is running asynchronously.

Comment: my bad i forgot to add the problem : "instead of reading the xml file tag one by one i want to read the tags that are inside the ITEMS tag and extract the value of each one"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:use `node.firstChild.nodeType === 3 && node.firstChild.textContent.trim() !== ''` to filter the text;

```
    var xmlDoc;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'prueba.xml');
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            xmlDoc = xhr.responseXML;
            var items = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("*");
            let res = {};
            Array.from(items).forEach(node => {
                if (node.firstChild.nodeType === 3 && node.firstChild.textContent.trim() !== '') {
                    res[node.nodeName] = node.firstChild.textContent
                }
            });
            console.log(res);//{timestamp: "1510794812", nombre: "ayy"}
        }
    }
```

Comment: wow thanks man, now i just need to turn them into a variable and assign them the value and it's all set ;p